# Does halacha provide suggestions on what we should occupy our minds with?

Tags: halacha, thought

Throughout the day, I find my thoughts wandering. I’ve recently been thinking whether Halacha provides any suggestions, or mandates, on what should be going though our mind (not during times of Tefilla, or Learning, but perhaps during working hours…)

The first thing I thought of was perhaps the six constant mitvos. I am looking for any sources from Chaazal or Poskim that give ideas on what we should be thinking about throughout the day.

Comment: One of the early debates between Hassidim and Mitnagdim was whether we should pursue a consciousness of G-d's presence every waking second (Hassidim), or if it is appropriate when one is studying Torah to dedicate 100% of one's "RAM" to the technicalities of that particular topic (Mitnagdim).

Comment: So they only disagreed at times of learning, but otherwise agreed?

Comment: Chassidus teaches to contemplate the greatness of G-d and His Torah *before* learning so that there's a background awareness, but during the learning one should be 100% focused on the subject.

Comment: During the rest of the day, there's a concept of בכל דרכיך דעהו, finding G-dliness in the mundane, and using spare time to review one's learning. A classic (if extreme) example can be found in [this story](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/114960/jewish/The-Bottom-Line.htm).

Comment: To thoughts of Torah.

Comment: @yisrael I think that's up for debate as well. Recently you'll hear a lot of harmonization between the views, while some scholars feel there were much more significant disagreements in the early 1800s. R' Yoel Teitelbaum said he was the last true chassid, and the Brisker Rav the last true misnaged. See https://www.aishdas.org/rygb/forks.htm

Answer (score 1):

The very beginning of the [book of Psalms](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.1?lang=en) provides an answer to your question:

> **Blessed is the man** who does not walk in the counsel of the wicked, nor stands in the way of sinners, nor sits in the seat of scorners.
> **But his delight is in the Torah of the Lord; and in his Torah he meditates day and night.**

Comment: Although it is a fundamental source, the OP was specific asking for sources from chazal and poskim.

Comment: @N.T for one who just said not to use kabbala, you bring a source of meditation and contemplation, that is the largest portion of  kabbala.  Though I like the source, thank you. And I would agree with Shmuel.

Comment: @Gabriel The largest part of Kabbala is Kabbalah. Meditation and contemplation are tools. They have been called Kabbalah by more new age people (unfortunately including Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan), and seized upon by charlatans who try to monetize what they call "kabbalah".

Answer (score 0):

Any sefer on Mussar or Jewish Thought is filled with things to be thought about and internalized throughout the day.
Some specific thoughts are in Chovos Halevavos, the chapter on Cheshbon Hanefesh
Orchos Tzaddikim, the chapter Zechira

It's also a recurring theme in R Avigdor Miller, TorahanyTime has a shuir from him Wealth of Mind which I havent heard yet but assume it's on this topic

I also heard from him that in mussar yeshivos, they would take a passuk or thought and repeat it over and over until they internalize it.

Also helpful- R' Reuven Leuchter has a series on concentration on TorahDownloads which teaches you how to take one idea and think it over a long time without losing focus. Got me to focus on one thing for more than 10 seconds, so it clearly Really works.

Answer (score -2):

One should always have Hashem in mind. ***Always***.

So what does this mean.

Well every part of persons day is filled with positive and negative mitzvot.

If you were to perform them with Hashem in mind, you would be doing the mitzvoth in the highest caliber possibility. ***No*** this does not mean to be Ultra, Extra, Fanatic, Extreme, just being meticulous as you should be.

Think of it as hiring a contracture that knows what they are doing and is particular with their trade, compared to one who knows though is lazy or uninterested, there's a noticeable difference in quality.

I read in the book of rabbi Aryeh Kaplan, (Meditation and Cabbala)

Quotes Rabbi Yitzschak the Blind a great Spanish Cabbalist saying the following,

Picture the four letter name in your mind, both hays of the four letter should have a crown (like that of the tora) from there, your heart needs to meditate on the "Ayn Sof" = The infinite one. Your mind and heart MUST at all times be connected, meaning on the same page. Following warning, please be very careful, utmost caution must be taken care of on your location, it must always be clean, and your hands clean/pure.
______________________________________
If you are strong enough to hold it, you can be like such the rest of the day.

There's a rabbi on YouTube, whose name is Rabbi Ariel Bartzadok from kosher torah school, he has nine videos, on how to use the name for many more than just picturing it, you can fight evil, reorganize your thoughts and so much more.

Please go to the following link, the videos with the name in the background are videos.

https://www.youtube.com/@koshertorahschoolofrabbiar9394

Here's a secrete, If your strong and sensitive, you can experience what it feels like to be in the presence of g-d, as your continues meditation will bring the vibration up, hence being in the presence of such, this will also be the reason why you must be clean at all times. It's not a joke and should be taken seriously or you can very well be profaning his name.

So what does it mean to have pure hands?

Please note (If you do have to do the following, you have go and rewash with the netilat yadayim cup, the ritual form of washing).

No scratching the head or any part of the body that is usually covered,
No nose picking,
No touching of anything that is impure, like garbage, or anything that has a foul odor, cleaning (that requires you touch things that are not clean)
Touching your shoes, soul of the shoes or even feet.
If you passed gas you must remove yourself from the location to where you can't smell the foul odor.
Needles to say, dead bodies, people that did not wash their hands in the mooring, or after using the washroom.
(Shulchan Aruch, orach chayim, hilchot teffilin, tefilot).

There are those that are extreme or for a better way to put it, have a different philosophy, that is, g-d is with me, in heaven and in hell, when I'm clean and when I'm not, because there's not a place where he's not, not only that, our bodies naturally produce foul odors within, that we can't do anything about, so he's with me when I'm clean and when I'm not. NEVERTHELES you must not and can not just jump into this different method as you lack experience, and credibility in heaven to be granted such leniency. Again to be tricked by those that will come and argue by saying that the statement still stand, there's not a place where he's not... As that is true though, that does not mean we can do as we wish, as there are boundaries that we cannot surpass unless we have created that authentic connection with heaven and g-d. Besides these individuals, have a very strong connection with the presence and not the image that we just spoke about, they can transform the impure energy through learning and doing great positive deeds.

If you're going to be mediocre or unwilling to, then please hold this to your prayers and personal moments that you would like to connect with him.

What is mediocre, don't treat the image with a lazy attitude, with a lesser mind, i.e. depressive, or just simply not giving the proper grander to that is required to give to his name (his presence) This is almost forcing you to always be happy, and or be a great person, this is done by expanding yourself to a great degree, as in whom you are as a person that g-d created, and dedicate to him and so on.

Why is this important, because your are inherently going to activate a very powerful energy, that you CANNOT disrespect, and by Disrespecting yourself you are by default disrespecting his name causing a major sin, that may be considered irreparable until after death.

Please note, you cannot waist your words talking nonsense, why, because this will be considered wasteful, now you are allowed to talk about work, relationships, and things along the line, though pointless chatter, gossip etc will get you in trouble.

As was pointed out by @Rabbi Kaii, the dress code should be according to Halacha, no not Black and white, just clean and modest, it could be a nice pair of jeans with a checkered shirt, or a polo, just nothing that goes in the ways of the goyim, or that draws to much attention, flamboyancy, you may dress classy, fancy if that's your regular code, though you may not start to dress to impress, or to show off, as this will be ga'ava and another form of degrading his name. So it's an intense, internal personal journey, that you should go through in my opinion, either way, you must be truthful with yourself and dress to beautify or enhance the name(presence that you will be in). Incase I need to state the obvious, the undergarments must be clean at all times, if your are going to sweat a lot, it would be best to withhold on the meditation (image) until when you are clean and if you would like to go through the day as such, you should hold it until you can find a way to resolve the excessive sweating throughout the day.

Hope this helps to answer your question, and not redirected you or left you unsatisfied.

Thank you,

Have a good day!

Comment: Please please distance yourself from people who teach kabbalah to the masses. They are all frauds, every one of them.

Comment: @N.T Excuse me? Whom are you to say such things. You know I was told by a great teacher an important lesson.     Don't talk what you don't know.  If you want to be golden, be silent. Thank you.

Comment: Teaching Kabbalah to the masses is expressly forbidden in Chagigah 2:1. This is very well known. See this link, esp. page 33: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Faith_and_Folly/EJ5eGUhNsVgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover

Comment: @N.T. Well the Tana Rabbi Shimon Bar-yochay will disagree to the point of stating "best that he not be born". (Sefer Or Ne'erav)

Comment: You can't take a statement out of context to disagree with a halacha. And in matters of halacha, we usually do not pasken like R' Shimon bar Yochai. This was part of the Maharshal's opposition to deciding Halacha based on Zohar. The most widely acknowledged Kabbalist of the generation is R' Yaakov Hillel, and I linked to his book on the subject.

Comment: @N.T. There are many that do not follow rabbi Yaakove hillel, A follow Other renowned Rabbis, Such as the Full Pinto Family, The Full Abuchatzera Family, Rabbi Yaakov  Addes, The Chief Rabbi of Safed a city that houses most of the  Kabbalist and son of the former Chief Rabbi in Israel Rabbi Shmuel Eliyahu. Rabbi Yaakov is only a representative for the western world, yes he is a big rabbi, not going to argue, though he's not the only one and thats a factual statement, in the ranking of Kabbalist, he would not be top three, or five, maybe top ten.

Comment: @N.T. Also we can remove the modern rabbis, and simply quote rabbi Cordovero, whom writes in his book, or ne'erav, that one should learn, even if they are not well versed in the basic teachings. And he goes on to say, one should find a true/real teacher, though if he can't find one, he should not wait and continue on his own. Teaching kabbala should be done like any other subject, through knowing your materials. I can't teach what I don't know, and if I do anyone will know right away that it's not real.